# Cannot load pdb in IDA Free 7.6

Tags: ida

I am new to reverse engineering. I am following a tutorial for Windows Reverse Engineering and IDA is a pretty good software for this approach.

I have just installed the last version of free IDA (7.6) on my Kali linux.
A have an .exe and .pdb. The exe is correctly loaded.

If I ask to load the pdb file, I have an error just after clicking on the button:

[image]

And in the output console:

[image]

Can someone help me please ?
I have tested with "root" user, same problem. Apparently the plugin is integrated to IDA now so no download is available.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Igor is probably better equipped to answer this, but I think the error message says it all. You'll need to have dbghelp.dll (part of the Windows SDKs and WinDbg redistributable packages) and it's unlikely that this exists on _any_ Linux (unless running IDA under Wine). I may be wrong about this, since MS has made some info available about the PDB format and so generally it's possible to make sense of it without dbghelp.dll, but I don't know if IDA has any home-brew implementation of this which would work natively on Linux.

Comment: Wonderful... Thank you :) I had to use IDA on a separate Windows machine (I like to separate analysis machine/ test subject hosting machine), because not fully working on Linux apparently. A shame that it was no warned before opening .exe file ... for beginners it could be a little bit frustrating (Any way: first Buffer Overflow exploit for me today :D).